# calling stored procedure with Oracle data provider .net with two or more definitions (error PLS-00307)

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I'm using Oracle Data Provider .net to interact with an Oracle database. I need to call a sample stored procedure but...

The stored procedures is in an oracle package where there is another stored procedure with the same name and number of parameters (but different parameters types).
When I try to call the stored procedure Oracle Data Provider can't resolve the "overload"... any suggestions?

I called the stored procedure in the classic mode:

```
define new **OracleCommand()** ...
add n **OracleParameter** ...
**ExecuteNonQuery()**
```

AFTER ExecuteNonQuery() an Exception is thrown with the following message:

```
**PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'storedProcedure name' match this call ORA-06550**
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you have provided are not sufficiently unambiguous for Oracle to decide which of the two stored procedures with the same name to call.

In particular, NULL values tend to cause such problems.

Please provide the full declaration of the two procedures and the VB.NET code for call the procedure. Then we can give explicit recommendations.